# Revolution slider blink once on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, revolution-slider

I have problem with revolution slider - first slide background image appears for a second before initialization, after that show spinner for one second and after all start showing slider. I tried with page.on load and  `jQuery(document).ready`, but nothing change.

Here is my slider code :

```
  foreach ($homeSliders as $homeSlider)
            {
    ?>
                <li
                        <?php if(isset($homeSlider->effect->title) and $homeSlider->effect->title!=''){
                            echo 'data-transition="'.$homeSlider->effect->title.'"';
                        }else{
                            echo 'data-transition="fade"';
                        } ?> >
                    <img src="<?= $homeSlider->getImg($homeSlider->id) ?>" <?=($homeSlider->kenburns == 1 ? $ken : '')?>>
                    <div class="tp-caption <?=$homeSlider->title_show?> tp-resizeme revo-slider-caps-text uppercase"
                         data-x="450"
                         data-y="150"
                         data-speed="400"
                         data-start="1000"
                         data-easing="<?=$homeSlider->title_show?>"
                         data-splitin="none"
                         data-splitout="none"
                         data-elementdelay="0.01"
                         data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                         data-endspeed="1000"
                         data-endeasing="Power4.<?=$homeSlider->title_show?>" style=""><img src="<?= $homeSlider->getImgProduct($homeSlider->id) ?>" alt="<?=$homeSlider->title?>"></div>
                    <?php if ($homeSlider->title) { ?>
                    <div class="tp-caption <?= $homeSlider->title_show ?> tp-resizeme revo-slider-emphasis-text nopadding noborder tp-resizing-positions"
                         data-x="<?=$homeSlider->title_top?>"
                         data-y="<?=$homeSlider->title_left?>"
                         data-speed="700"
                         data-start="1200"
                         data-easing="<?= $homeSlider->effect->title ?>"
                         data-splitin="none"
                         data-splitout="none"
                         data-elementdelay="0.01"
                         data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                         data-endspeed="1000"
                         data-endeasing="Power4.easeOutCubic" style=" color: <?=$homeSlider->title_color?>; max-width: 730px; width: auto; white-space: normal; line-height: 1.15; font-size: <?=$homeSlider->title_size?>px!important; min-width: 250px;"><?=($homeSlider->title ? $homeSlider->title : '' )?></div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if ($homeSlider->description) { ?>
                    <div class="tp-caption customin <?= $homeSlider->description_show ?> tp-resizeme revo-slider-desc-text tp-resizing-positions"
                         data-x="<?=$homeSlider->description_top?>"
                         data-y="<?=$homeSlider->description_left?>"
                         data-speed="700"
                         data-start="1400"
                         data-customin="x:0;y:150;z:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:1;scaleY:1;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:200;transformOrigin:50% 0%;"
                         data-easing="<?= $homeSlider->effect->title ?>"
                         data-splitin="none"
                         data-splitout="none"
                         data-elementdelay="0.01"
                         data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                         data-endspeed="1000"
                         data-endeasing="Power4.easeOutCubic" style="text-align: left; color: <?=$homeSlider->description_color?>; max-width: 550px; white-space: normal; font-size: <?=$homeSlider->description_size?>px!important;"><?=($homeSlider->description ? $homeSlider->description : '')?></div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if ($homeSlider->link) { ?>
                    <div class="tp-caption <?= $homeSlider->button_show ?> tp-resizeme tp-resizing-positions"
                         data-x="<?=$homeSlider->button_top?>"
                         data-y="<?=$homeSlider->button_left?>"
                         data-speed="700"
                         data-start="1550"
                         data-easing="<?= $homeSlider->effect->title ?>"
                         data-splitin="none"
                         data-splitout="none"
                         data-elementdelay="0.01"
                         data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                         data-endspeed="1000"
                         data-endeasing="Power4.<?= $homeSlider->effect->title ?>" class="button button-border button-large button-rounded tright nomargin hero-action-btn"><span style=" color: <?=$homeSlider->button_color?>; font-size: <?=$homeSlider->button_size?>px!important; background-color: transparent !important; border: 2px solid #22afeb; padding: 0.5em 2em !important; border-radius: 5px !important; line-height: 1.3em !important;"><a href="<?= $homeSlider->link; ?>" >more</span> <i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a></div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

and js :

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.tp-banner').show().revolution(
            {
                dottedOverlay:"none",
                delay:16000,
                startwidth:1140,
                startheight:600,
                hideThumbs:200,

                navigationType:"bullet",
                navigationArrows:"solo",
                navigationStyle:"preview4",

                navigation: {
                    keyboardNavigation:"on",
                    keyboard_direction: "horizontal",
                    mouseScrollNavigation:"off",
                    onHoverStop:"off",
                    touch:{
                        touchenabled:"on",
                        swipe_threshold: 75,
                        swipe_min_touches: 1,
                        swipe_direction: "horizontal",
                        navigationType:"bullet",
                        drag_block_vertical: false
                    }
                    ,
                    arrows: {
                        style:"zeus",
                        enable:true,
                        hide_onmobile:true,
                        hide_under:600,
                        hide_onleave:true,
                        hide_delay:200,
                        hide_delay_mobile:1200,
                        left: {
                            h_align:"left",
                            v_align:"center",
                            h_offset:0,
                            v_offset:0
                        },
                        right: {
                            h_align:"right",
                            v_align:"center",
                            h_offset:70,
                            v_offset:0
                        }
                    } ,
                    bullets: {
                        enable: true,
                        container:"slider",
                        hide_onmobile: false,
                        style: "ares",
                        hide_onleave: false,
                        direction: "horizontal",
                        h_align: "center",
                        v_align: "bottom",
                        h_offset: 0,
                        v_offset: 30,
                        space: 3,
                        rtl:false,
                        tmp: ''
                    }
                },


                touchenabled:"on",
                onHoverStop:"on",

                swipe_velocity: 0.7,
                swipe_min_touches: 1,
                swipe_max_touches: 1,
                drag_block_vertical: false,

                parallax:"mouse",
                parallaxBgFreeze:"on",
                parallaxLevels:[7,4,3,2,5,4,3,2,1,0],

                keyboardNavigation:"off",

                navigationHAlign:"center",
                navigationVAlign:"bottom",
                navigationHOffset:0,
                navigationVOffset:0,

                soloArrowLeftHalign:"left",
                soloArrowLeftValign:"center",
                soloArrowLeftHOffset:0,
                soloArrowLeftVOffset:0,

                soloArrowRightHalign:"right",
                soloArrowRightValign:"center",
                soloArrowRightHOffset:20,
                soloArrowRightVOffset:0,

                shadow:0,
                fullWidth:"on",
                fullScreen:"off",

                stopLoop: 'off',
                stopAfterLoops: -1,
                stopAtSlide: -1,
                shuffle:"off",

                autoHeight:"off",
                forceFullWidth:"off",

                hideThumbsOnMobile:"off",
                hideNavDelayOnMobile:1500,
                hideBulletsOnMobile:"off",
                hideArrowsOnMobile:"off",
                hideThumbsUnderResolution:0,

                hideSliderAtLimit:0,
                hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
                hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
                startWithSlide:0,
                fullScreenOffsetContainer: ".header"
            });
    }); //ready
```

Comment: Check browser console errors if any, that can be helpful.. post if there are any errors